# Knockout binding to jQuery templates - HTML strings are encoded

Tags: knockout.js

Am I right in saying that Knockout encodes HTML values when binding to a jQuery template.

How do I stop this? In the example below the ${Description} contains HTML tags that I do not want encoded.

```
<script id="QuoteHeaderTemplate" type="text/x-jQuery-tmpl">
<div class="heading group">
<div id="${Name}" class="title row group">
    <div class="inner">
        <a class="benefit-title" href="#">${Name}</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="description group">
    <div class="inner">
        ${Description}
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</script>

<div data-bind='template: {name: "QuoteHeaderTemplate", foreach: benefits}'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to use the `{{html}}` tag provided by the jQuery Templates plugin.  Docs are here: http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-html/

You would do: `{{html Description}}`